# How do I create a custom REST api in Plone

Tags: plone

I need to provide a REST call from Plone to another service. Do I need to integrate something like Flask into Plone or can I do it without any other framework/library?

Answer (score 6):

You can build your own REST API in plone with plone.rest:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.rest

plone.rest will most likely become part of Plone core at some point.

If you want a ready-to-use out-of-the-box solution have a look at plone.restapi:

https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi

There is no plone.restapi alpha release yet. Though, there will be one soon.